# Replace URL parameter separator with .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

A WP plugin is generating URLs with `?` parameter separator, instead of `&`

Something like: `https://yourdomain.com/?quiz=lesson-1-quiz-1?id=1260`

Is it possible to leave first `?` as it is and replace all other with `&` using .htaccess?

The URL should be: `https://yourdomain.com/?quiz=lesson-1-quiz-1&id=1260`

Comment: @anubhava yes, there can be multiple separators (?)

Comment: @anubhava no, maximum 2

Comment: If you can then properly set this PHP ini parameter https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.arg-separator.output

Comment: If you can access the plugin code then find https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php and make it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^?]*)\?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&%2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this rule as your topmost rule:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\?[^?]*)\?(\S*)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}%1&%2 [L,R=302,NE]

# all other rules go below this line
```

Once you've tested this rule, don't forget to change `302` to `301`.